# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC / C# : one-to-many get data from many side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to access the data on the many side of a one to many relationship. In the Index action of my controller I assign the data to a variable and return it. I have a Blog, the one side, with many posts. I just want to list the blogs with their posts in the view.

For example...

```
Blog1
    post1
    post2
    post3
Blog2
    post1
    post2
```

That's pretty much it. But as it stands, in the view, I am unable to access the post data.

Here are my models with the relevant properties

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post>? Posts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var applicationDbContext = _context.Blogs
            .Include(b => b.BlogUsers)
            .Include(p => p.Posts)
            .ToListAsync();

    return View(await applicationDbContext);
}
```

I've included the `Posts` so I should be able to access the `Post` data. I can access the `Blogs` data no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is configured your entity mapping?

Comment: What's your  BlogUsers ? Do you get any errors ?

Comment: I can access the BlogUsers, e.g. ````@item.BlogUsers.FullName```` works. But if I type ````@item.Posts.````, none of the properties appear in the intellisence after the dot.

Comment: As far as the entity mapping, if I understand it correctly, I'm just using what I posted, no base classes or OnModelCreating. I'm leaving it to EF to do that. Again I don't understand the entity mapping enough, so I apologize if there is any confusion in my attempt to answer your question.

Comment: I can access the BlogUsers, e.g. ````@item.BlogUsers.FullName```` works. But if I type ````@item.Posts.````, none of the properties appear in the intellisence after the dot. For example I was hoping that ````@item.Posts.Title```` would work, but "Title" does not show up as an option, and the error says "ICollection<Post> does not contain a definition for 'Title'".

Comment: The view uses ````@model IPagedList<Blog>````. I'm not sure if the PagedList extension has anything to do with it but I thought I'd mention it just in case. I can access the Blog and BlogUsers properties, just not the Posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Posts you can try:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
             var applicationDbContext = await _context.Blogs
              .Include(b => b.BlogUsers)
              .Include(p => p.Posts)
              .ToListAsync();
            return View(applicationDbContext);
        }
```

If you want `@item.Posts.`, the properties appear in the intellisence after the dot.  You need to use

```
public virtual Post? Posts { get; set; }
```

Because `ICollection<Post>` don't have a definition for Id. We define the Id in the Post .

> For example I was hoping that @item.Posts.Title would work,

Try:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)                 
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
       @* @item.Posts.Id*@
            @foreach (var item2 in item.Posts)
            {
                 @item2.Title
            }
        }
```

Comment: @David Have a try with two `@foreach`

Comment: If i change ````ICollection<Post>```` to the ````public virtual Post? Posts { get; set; }```` in my model, would that mess up my application?

Comment: The nested ````@foreach```` didn't work. It did not throw an error but also nothing appeared in the view for that ````@foreach```` block.

Comment: @David  yes, that mess up my application, so I suggest you try two `@foreach` . And keep your `ICollection<Post>`.

Comment: @David I can get the title,  like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/19qng.png

Comment: Ok, I'm getting strange behavior. The first ````item.Name```` is showing the blog name, but the ````item1.Title```` is showing the name of the second blog in the list.  I believe this is because there is a conflict with the XPagedList nuget package, because the first two blogs listed on page 1 are showing  up in the ````item.Name```` and ````item1.Title```` . When I go to page two, the same occurs, showing the next 2 blog names in the list. I will have to do some research on this. Thanks for all your help though. I know where the problem is now.